# How to get text within a tag selenium webdriver php

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to fetch next within

```
    <a data-b="11" href="/search;_ylt=A0SO80abFo5S31sAGI9XNyoA?p=test&amp;fr=sfp&amp;b=11&amp;pstart=2" id="pg-next">Next</a>
```

Getting Error AS:

PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class RemoteWebElement could not
 be converted to string

Comment: What are you really trying to do? 'Fetch' the text, or actually click on the link?
What have you tried? Pasting a HTML snippet and an error message isn't going to get you much help. Show some code

Comment: Sir I want to use WebdriverBy::linktext() so How to go ahead

Comment: In your latest question you're asking how to install Selenium, and I'm going to guess you've already googled and found this page http://codeception.com/11-12-2013/working-with-phpunit-and-selenium-webdriver.html. so do you actually have anything running that you're able to execute?

Comment: @steveCrawford: Sir I have installed successfully in centos operating System.But not in windows.